# CSS: How do I place objects under absolutely positioned objects?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="header-shapes">
        <img class="circle" src="images/home/circle.png" alt="">
        <img class="triangle" src="images/home/triangle.png" alt="">
        <img class="square" src="images/home/square.png" alt="">
</div>

<table>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>

</table>
```

I want the header-shapes div to take up the whole screen and the table to appear under header-shapes. Here is my problem: I want the table to appear after these images. However, since the images within header-shapes are positioned absolutely, the table appears *on top* of the header-shapes div instead of appearing after.

How do I make the table appear *after* the images I placed?

My initial solution was to do:

```
table {
    margin-top: 500px; 
}
```

but this feels very brute forced.

I was also thinking of doing:

```
.header-shapes  {
    height: 768px;
}
```

Which seems to work but I don't know if this is a very professional way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you even need absolute position to begin with?

Comment: Use absolute property along with z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the `position:absolute;` to make the table appear below your shapes. if you really want to use position absolute ,add a relative positioned container with height ,before your absolutely positioned items.

```
<div class="header-parent">
<div class="header-shapes">
    <img class="circle" src="images/home/circle.png" alt="">
    <img class="triangle" src="images/home/triangle.png" alt="">
    <img class="square" src="images/home/square.png" alt="">
```

```
.header-parent {
position:relative;
height: 500px;
```

}